# Entity Framework With Complex Relationships

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, t-sql

I have a data set which is an number of independent objects (person, property, job) and each of those are related to another object (note).

The relationship is formed by a foreign key (the primary in person, property or job) and a type which is simply a varchar field.

So note looks basically like:

```
Id
RecordId(foreign key)
RecordType(person, propery, job as varchar)
Note Detail
```

The problem faced is, each of the primary objects may have the same key so when using entityframework with include the person may have job notes. I can filter this later with a where RecordType=='XYZ' clause which I feel is messy. Sadly the include lacks the ability to 'include where'.

Could any one suggest an alternative approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had similar issues. One solution is to have a Table Per Hierarchy relationship. You end up with a Note(base class) and PersonNote, PropertyNote, etc. Curiously, EF wants an additional field for each type of reference, so your table will need fields RecordId_1, RecordId_2, etc. in addition to the existing RecordId. It's a little unintuitive if you aren't generating the database with Code First.

The other solution I use is to create views in the db that do the desired filtering, combining the note and the source record, then just mapping EF to the views.